# Citations not generating in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, citations

new to Stackoverflow, and relatively new to writing documents in RMarkdown. I have most other things down, however, I cannot generate citations and the bibliography in RMarkdown. For the example code below, I have used the \cite{REFNAME} as well as [@REFNAME] syntax. The [@REFNAME] will not even let the document be generated, the \cite{} generates the document but the citation is [?] and the reference is not after the #References section.

I have looked through this site and I cannot get suggested fixes to work. I am hoping that the error I am showing after the code sections will tell someone what the error really is.

````
---
title: "Title for my document"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
   pdf_document:
     fig_caption: yes
     keep_tex: true
     number_sections: true
geometry: margin=0.5in
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
urlcolor: blue
bibliography: bibliography_file.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

knitr::knit_hooks$set(mysize = function(before, options, envir) {
if (before) 
return(options$size)
})

```

text written \cite{neil_increasing_2008} more text written


# References
````

My .bib file entry looks like this

```
@article{neil_increasing_2008,
title = {Increasing incidence of legionellosis in the {United} {States}, 
1990-2005: changing epidemiologic trends.},
volume = {47},
journal = {Clinical Infectious Diseases},
author = {Neil, K. and Berkelman, R.},
year = {2008},
pages = {591--599}
}
```

The error is:

> Warning message: LaTeX Warning(s):   Citation `neil_increasing_2008'
>   on page 1 undefined on input lin   There were undefined references.

If I use the [@neil_increasing_2008] as opposed to the \cite{} then the following error is generate, and it does not generate the document either

> pandoc-citeproc: Cannot decode byte '\x87':
>   Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
>   pandoc.exe: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc Filter returned error
>   status 1 Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
>   Execution halted

Comment: Try `bookdown::pdf_document2`

Comment: Thanks Martin. I looked into that and this morning went down the full Sweave rabbit hole. I think this works well. I will look into Bookdown more. Is there a particular value of learning that one? Is that a way of being able to use the knitr to generate word documents through RMarkdown? Wish I didn't need to generate those, but still do sometimes :=)

Comment: Your example works fine for me when using `[@neil_increasing_2008]`.  From the text of the error message, it sounds as though you have some non-ascii characters elsewhere in your `.bib` file.  You can find them using the R function `showNonASCIIfile("bibliography_file.bib")`.  That file should use a UTF-8 encoding to work with Pandoc; you might be able to just re-encode it if your text editor supports that.

Comment: Wow, I think I am going to pull my hair out. It works for me now too. What could I have done wrong?